# приведение типов C#

Tags: c#

```
public interface ICloneable
{
    object Clone();
}
class Person : ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Person { Name = this.Name, Age = this.Age };
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person { Name="Tom", Age = 23 };
        Person p2 = (Person)p1.Clone();
        p2.Name = "Alice";
        Console.WriteLine(p1.Name); // Tom

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Вопрос: почему экземпляр р1 при вызове метода Clone() приводится к типу Person? 
Он ведь и так является объектом Person.

Comment: `[KO mode ON]` Потому что Clone() возвращает object `[KO mode OFF]` [ICloneable.Clone - метод ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Действительно - public object Clone(). Спасибо за помощь невнимательному студенту.

Comment: К типу `Person` приводится не `p1`, а результат выполнения `p1.Clone()`

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `public object Clone()` возвращает объект типа `object`. Поэтому и необходимо приведение.